# We see a bug on Mondays. We are now told it is fixed. How do I simulate Monday for re-testing?

Tags: manual-testing

I don't really want to wait until Monday to validate this fix. Is there a way I can do something at the back-end to simulate it being Monday?

Comment: what caused it on Mondays only?

Comment: Is the date check on the server or on the client?

Comment: What platform, what tools, etc?

Answer (score 4):

First, figure out where the application gets its sense of time from. Then, figure out how you can either change the time/date there or how you can mock that thing to make the application believe that it's the date/time you want.

Comment: This should go without saying but it's especially important for this sort of time-dependent or hard to reproduce bug: whatever is done to "fake" the time should be tested both on the old and new versions of the code. If it doesn't trigger the bug in the code that _doesn't_ have the fix, it isn't a valid test for the code that _does_ have the supposed fix.